# First-order logic and quantifiers

Tags: logic, quantifiers

In "G"odel's Incompleteness Theorems" (p. 29), R. Smullyan gives the axioms of a version of first-order logic with identity (Kalish & Montague) as:

L1: $(F \supset (G\supset F))$

L2: $(F\supset (G\supset H))\supset ((F\supset G) \supset (F\supset H))$

L3: $((\sim F\supset \sim G)\supset (G\supset F))$

L4: $(\forall v(F\supset G)\supset (\forall v F\supset \forall v G))$

L5:  $(F\supset \forall v F)$ ($v$ does not occur in $F$).

L6: $\exists v(v=t)$ ($v$ does not occur in $t$).

L7: $(v=t \supset (XvY \supset XtY))$ (Where $XvY$ is an atomic formula).

Here $F, G, H $ are formulas, $t$ is a term (the notion depends on the language, but let's say we're talking first-order arithmetic, in which case a 'term', roughly consists of variables, numerals, + and .) and $v$ is a variable. Further, the rules of inference are 1) Modus ponens and 2) from $F$ infer $\forall v F$.

So here's my question: How do you prove **any** formula of the type $\exists v F$? Doesn't look like you can get much from L6. The reason for my question is that after this (p. 61), when discussing $\omega$-consistency, he argues that from $F(\bar n)$ provable for some $n$ follows $\exists v F(v)$ provable.

Comment: Does the logic ever allow a non-variable term on the left side of $=$?

Comment: Can you double check if you typed L5 and your second rule of inference correctly?  Normally one of those will be reversed for Hilbert axioms.

Comment: @DanielV Checked

Comment: L5, inference (1), and inference (2) are redundant.  Usually inference (2) in Hilbert axioms would be "from $\forall v F$ infer $F[t/v]$ + some restrictions"

Comment: @DanielV: You can't have _both_ inference rules be redundant. If you remove them, you can't conclude anything but the axioms themselves.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Right, but inference 2 doesn't add anything when L5 and modus ponens are present.  The 3 contain a redundancy; which combined with the normal way of presenting Hilbert axioms suggests that inference 2 was transcribed incorrectly.

Comment: @DanielV: Inference 2 works even when $v$ is free in $F$. On the other hand, simply having inference 2 will not allow you to derive L5.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It is less trivial than I originally thought.  But I think inference 2 is still redundant by induction on proof $F(t)$.  Without inference 2, if you can prove $F(t)$, then you can prove $\forall t~F(t)$ by transform: inductively, if the last step of the proof of $F(t)$ was modus ponens $A(t) \to F(t),A(t) \vdash F(t)$, then inductively establish $\forall t~ A(t) \to F(t)$, $\forall t~A(t)$, and use L4 to establish $\forall t~F(t)$.  Similarly L5 can be used to establish the quantified versions of L1 through L3.  Still seems like a transcription error to include inference 2.

Comment: @HenningMakholm But I didn't notice the difference in free variables that you mentioned (thanks) and didn't notice the how L4/L5 can be used to establish a proof of $\forall t~F(t)$ from a proof $F(t)$ until you challenged me on it.  It looks almost like L4 and L5 were chosen because of their ability to make inf 2 redundant, similarly to how L1/L2 are chosen in order to make the deduction theorem redundant.

Comment: @DanielV: L5 _cannot_ be used to "establish quantified versions of L1 through L3" if the quantified-over variable appears free in the L1,2,3 instance.

Comment: For example, how would you prove $\forall x(Fx\supset (Gx \supset Fx))$ without inference 2?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah you are right.  Thanks for the instruction.  Without Inference2 it looks tentatively to me like there is no way to establish a statement of the form $\forall x~F$ where $x$ is free in $F$.  Why do they have the variable restriction on L5?  Are they afraid that $Ax \to \forall x ~Ax$ might be interpreted as $(\exists x~ Ax) \to (\forall x~ Ax)$ or something?

Comment: @DanielV: More or less, yes: Without the restriction on L5 you would be able to derive $\forall x(Ax\to\forall x\,Ax)$, which is not valid.

Comment: @hmakholmleftoverMonica But why couldn't you obtain this (invalid) formula by applying inference rule (2)?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the shortest possible way to do it, but here is how to prove $\exists x (Fx \supset Fx)$. For brevity's sake, I will not show the proofs of propositional validities (anything provable from L1$-$L3 alone).

1. $Fx \supset Fx$: Any formula of the form $\alpha \rightarrow \alpha$ is provable from L1$-$L3.
2. $x = y \supset (Fx \supset Fx)$: Weaking of 1., immediate with L1 and MP.
3. $\neg (Fx \supset Fx) \supset \neg (x = y)$: Contraposition of 2., provable from L1$-$L3.
4. $\forall x (\neg (Fx \supset Fx) \supset \neg (x = y))$: From 3. by inference (2).
5. $\forall x[\neg (Fx \supset Fx)] \supset \forall x[\neg (x=y)]$: From 4. by using L4 and MP.
6. $\forall x[\neg (Fx \supset Fx)] \supset \neg\neg\forall x[\neg (x=y)]$: Inserting double negation (derivable because $\alpha \supset \neg\neg\alpha$ and transitivity are derivable from L1$-$L3).
7. $\forall x[\neg (Fx \supset Fx)] \supset \neg \exists x(x=y)$: Putting $\exists x$ for $\neg\forall x\neg$ (by definition)
8. $\exists x (x = y) \supset \neg\forall x[\neg(Fx \supset Fx)]$: Contraposition of 6.
9. $\neg\forall x[\neg(Fx \supset Fx)]$: From 8. by using L6 and MP.
10. $\exists x (Fx \supset Fx)$: Again putting $\exists x$ for $\neg\forall x\neg$.

**Edit:** I've fiddled around with the calculus a bit more, and and as a simple example of universal instantiation, here is a how to derive $\forall x(Fx)\supset Ft$ (this will also work if we put a function expression or so for $t$, as long as $x$ doesn't occur in $t$, because of step 4)

1. $x=t \supset (Fx \supset Ft)$: Instance of L7
2. $\neg Ft \supset (Fx \supset \neg(x=t))$: Derivable from 1., because $(\alpha \supset (\beta \supset \gamma)) \supset (\neg\gamma \supset (\beta \supset \neg\alpha))$ is propositionally valid and provable from L1$-$L3.
3. $\forall x(\neg Ft) \supset \forall x[Fx \supset \neg(x=t)]$: From 2. by applying inference (2) and L4.
4. $\neg Ft \supset \forall x (\neg Ft)$: Instance of L5
5. $\forall x [Fx \supset \neg(x=t)] \supset (\forall x(Fx) \supset \forall x (\neg x=t))$: Instance of L4
6. $\neg Ft \supset (\forall x(Fx) \supset \forall x (\neg x=t))$: From 4., 3., 5. by transitivity.
7. $\neg \forall x (\neg x=t)$: Instance of L6
8. $\neg Ft \supset \neg \forall x (Fx)$: From 6. and 7. by propositional logic
9. $\forall x (Fx) \supset Ft$: Contraposition of 8.

Note that this does not automatically transfer if we put more complex formulae for $Fx$, since we would first have to extend L7. For instance, if we want to use this scheme to derive $Ft \supset \exists x (Fx)$, we need to prove $x=t \supset (\neg Fx \supset \neg Ft)$ as a starting point.

Comment: Well done. And good grief, that's complex.

Answer (score 0):

For that matter, how do you *use* a formula of the type $\exists vF$?

The most likely assumption is that $\exists vF$ is considered to be an abbreviation for ${\sim}\forall v\,{\sim}F$ -- and you can then prove it using propositional reasoning together with the rules for $\forall$.

Comment: So, if you have a proof of $F(\bar n)$, how to you get a proof of $\sim \forall v \sim F(v)$?? The question is about provable, not about true

Comment: Just checked: Henning's assumption is correct -- the original Kalish/Montague paper has for L6 the version with a negated universal quantifier.

Comment: You get  a proof of something of the form ∼∀v∼F(v) by assuming ∀v∼F(v) and going for reductio: reductio is a derived rule of the propositional sub-system.

Comment: You seem to be saying (correct me if I'm wrong) that if $F(\bar n)$  is provable for all $n$, then $\forall v F(v)$ is also provable. This is mentioned explicitly as false on p. 73 of Smullyan. $n$ in all this is a natural number, of course.

Comment: In truth, it is not entirely clear to me how to complete the proof -- I can't seem to figure out how to justify universal instantiation from these rules, especially given the strangely asymmetric L7. @PeterSmith, are there any additional rules in the original that are missing here?

Comment: (i) To be fair, Smullyan in his previous chapter announces he is using the existential quantifier as an abbreviation for not-all-not. (ii) Tarski in a linked paper proves a version of instantiation, but -- and this is the oddity with this system -- making essential use of the identity axioms (and it comes 14 Lemmas in ...). Or so the quickest of skim-reads suggests ...

Comment: @DanielV: Universal instantiation infers $\phi(t)$ from $\forall x.\phi(x)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Isn't the point about universal instantiation that we have a proof system, not a deduction system? That is, we don't need a deduction rule like $\forall x.\phi(x) \vdash \phi(t)$, but only that if $\vdash \forall x . \phi(x)$ , then $\vdash \phi(t)$. And by examining the three ways how $\vdash \forall x . \phi(x)$ may be derived, it seems relatively straightforward that $\vdash \phi(t)$ is also derivable.

Comment: @DeeDuu What if $\forall x.\phi(x)$ isn't proven, but assumed?  Like you have an axiom of some theory that characterizes a relation $F$ as $\exists x.F(x) \to \forall x.F(x)$ and you want to establish $F(5) \vdash F(6)$ ?

Comment: @DanielV The calculus isn't made for arbitrary assumptions (which I meant by saying it's "not a deduction system"), but only for proving tautologies. Maybe the edit to my post helps out a bit more.